# Discord bot, current date as status

Tags: python, discord, bots

i have looked a bit and tried multiple things and im stumped. Im going to be hosting a discord bot 24/7 and i want the Status to display the current date and time, as example. 11/30/22, 10:51 PM, in eastern time. Thanks!

tried methods such as "
activity=discord.Game(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%H:%M")),"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tasks.loop`, creating a task that updates every minute and changes the bot's Status to the current time.

`tasks.loop` is a decorator which executes the decorated function repeatedly at a defined interval. Then you just need to spawn the loop in an asynchronous context, of which I personally use `setup_hook` in this example.

```
from discord.ext import tasks
import datetime

@tasks.loop(minutes=1):
async def set_status(): # name is unimportant, but it must not take arguments
  name = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%H:%M")
  activity = discord.Game(name=name)
  await client.change_presence(activity=activity)

@client.event
async def setup_hook(): # name is important, and it must not take arguments
  set_status.start()
```

Replacing `client` with the name of your client as appropriate (usually `client` or `bot`).